# Counting Number of cases that fall within 20 days

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks at incidence crime rate. The first time a city has a crime reported, we write it as 0. We want to compare the first crime a city has to its other crimes until we find a crime that has 20 days between them. When that happens, we then take that crime day, and compare it to the other crimes for a city, until we find 20 days. We code this with a 0 and 1, and the first crime for the city always gets a 0.

I know that might be confusing, so the data.frame below hopefully explains things better:

```
City     Days
City1    0
City1    4
City1    20
City2    0
City2    20
City3    0
City3    20
City3    30
```

So, the resulting data.frame would be

```
City     Days  Result
City1    0.     1
City1    4.     0
City1    20.    1
City2    0.     1
City2    20.    1
City3    0.     1
City3    20.    1
City3    30.    0
```

I currently have a convoluted nested for loop that loops through the cities, and their incidents. I have created an index, which changes if the difference a cities crime is greater than 20. I then update this. However, this has become tedious and an awful approach. Any alternatives would be appreciative.

Comment: What is the logic to create `Result` variable? What is 0 and what is 1?

Comment: For every city, we want to count the first crime (that’s why it always get a 1). We then see if the next crime happened at least 20 days ago. If it did, we give it a 1 and use that crime age to compare the next value for a city, looking for a difference of 20 days.

Comment: Why the 3rd row is 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for this solution

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(City) %>% 
  mutate(res = +(c(20, diff(Days)) >= 20)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 x 3
  City   Days   res
  <chr> <int> <int>
1 City1     0     1
2 City1     4     0
3 City1    20     0
4 City2     0     1
5 City2    20     1
6 City3     0     1
7 City3    20     1
8 City3    30     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag` to offset the days column to find the difference between crime days:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = "City     Days
City1    0
City1    4
City1    20
City2    0
City2    20
City3    0
City3    20
City3    30", header = TRUE) %>%
  as_tibble()


df %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  mutate(tmp = lag(Days),
         Result = ifelse(Days - tmp >= 20 | is.na(tmp), 1, 0)) %>%
  select(-tmp)
```